# Answers to this question involved facts, and yet it was closed as 'Not Constructive'. Why?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Answers to this question involved facts, and yet it was closed as 'Not Constructive'. Why?

[A single language to learn to develop desktop and mobile phone applications?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146009/a-single-language-to-learn-to-develop-desktop-and-mobile-phone-applications)

Comment: You are right, it should have been closed as [off topic](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/answers-to-this-question-involved-facts-and-yet-it-was-closed-as-not-construct#comment9523_3520)

Comment: @YannisRizos: But wasn't the OP asking if *any* language is capable of fulfilling this need, rather than polling for the "best one"?

Comment: Yes, but the need here is extremely broad, which makes the question prone to "favourite" answers as @maple_shaft explained.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basis of closing a question really doesn't have to do with the quality of the existing answers, it has to do with the quality of the current state of the question itself.

I agree there are some very high quality answers that manage to stay subjective, but anytime a question asks "the best language for X", well that is a highly opinionated thing.  One can make a valid argument for why Scala is superior because of Y and Z but in the end I may be super effective with Groovy just because I know it so well.

Besides that it had already gotten a close vote and it was flagged.

If the question can be improved then maybe it can be considered for reopening.

Comment: The question is off topic: "Programmers — Stack Exchange ... is not about ... what language you should learn next". Granted language choice as a category of questions was deemed off topic because the questions are horribly not constructive (for the reasons you explain), but technically the question is off topic.